# k6 same environment variables in multiple export functions

Tags: javascript, performance-testing, load-testing, build-automation, k6

Can I use same environment variables in multiple export function ?

```
export function login() {
    group('Login API', function () {
        __ENV.code = 'code getting from api response';
        console.log("code is : " + __ENV.code);             // getting correct value
    });
  group('Login API', function () {
        console.log("code is : " + __ENV.code);             // getting correct value
    });
}

export function api1() {
    group('1. APIs', function () {
        console.log(`code in 1 : ${__ENV.code}`);          // getting undefined value
    });
    group('2. APIs', function () {
        console.log("code in 2 : " + __ENV.code);          // getting undefined value
    })
}
```

If I'm using same env variable in same export function, then I'm getting correct value. Also I'm able to use same env variable on other pages/screens. But on same page if I'm using that env variable in different export function then I'm getting undefined response. As shown in above code.

**What's wrong I'm doing?** (I'm new(beginner) in K6)

Comment: It seems like you might be using `scenarios`, and have defined `code` as part of the `env` property only of the `login` scenario, but not the `api1` scenario?

Comment: I'm trying to use __ENV.code variable in all export functions. . I can use it in multiple groups but not in export function. Where as getting value from login function and using it in api1().

Comment: Have you read through https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/environment-variables and https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/scenarios ?

Comment: Yes. I got it. Checked -  (k6.io/docs/using-k6/scenarios)

Answer (score 0):

You can only set an environment variable from outside the script, for example by running `k6 run -e CODE=abc your_script.js`

You have then access to the value "abc" by *reading* `__ENV.CODE` in your script. You can *not* set it to a different value while the script is running (as you have found out).